# Why is pylint telling me that my dict attribute is an undefined variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint

I'm working with this code using pylint configured for python 3+:

```
import utils

valid_commands = ['category', 'help', 'exit']

def createCategory():
    utils.clear()
    category = {
        name: 'test' <- allegedly undefined
    }
    utils.insertCategory(category)

def listActions():
    utils.clear()
    for command in valid_commands:
        print(command)

def exit():
    utils.clear()

actions = {
    'category': createCategory,
    'help':     listActions,
    'exit':     exit
}

command = ''
while command != 'exit':
    command = input('task_tracker> ')
    if command in valid_commands:
        actions[command]()
```

I'm getting this error:

[image]

My code is running fine but the fact that this error won't go away is driving me nuts. Why is it telling me that this is undefined?

Comment: It should be the literal `'name'`. No variable called `name` is defined.

Comment: It is undefined, and the code does not run fine.

Comment: I feel like this is a duplicate, but I'm having trouble finding it

Answer (score 5):

Dictionary key should be either an immutable value, or a variable that contains an immutable value (like a string or a number). `name` isn't a string and isn't defined as a variable in the current scope. One way of fixing this would be

```
def createCategory():
    utils.clear()
    category = {
        'name': 'test'
    }
    utils.insertCategory(category)
```

Comment: If it is a variable, the variable should be immutable too. Maybe '... should be an immutable literal or variable'?